Creating a "dummy" button for a clickable container
TL; DR: Trying to make a dummy button with hover effect in a clickable container.
A preface: I'm looking for HTML/CSS solutions ONLY (I already know how to do this with JS).
I am working on a simple card design made of a container and a button link. I want the whole container to act as a link, i.e., the user can click anywhere inside the container to get to their destination. My goal is to do this without using multiple a elements.
The requirements for the behavior of this card are:

The user hovers over the button, and they see the button's hover effect.
The user hovers over the container, and they see NO hover effect on the button.
The user clicks anywhere within the container, including on the button, and it takes them to the linked page.

--- What I've tried ----
To avoid multiple a elements or wrapping the entire container in an a element, I went with the following approach:

I absolutely positioned the real a element to accept clicks from anywhere inside the container.

I created a dummy button div instead to replace the real a element, and brought it to the front so it can be hovered (using z-index).




.container {
  position: relative;
  /* This is the important one, the rest is styling */
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 16px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  z-index: 1;
  /* This is the important one, the rest is styling */
  width: min-content;
  height: min-content;
  padding: 8px;
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
}

.button:hover {
  background: darkred;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.cover {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
<div class="container">
  <a class="cover" href="#">Real link</a>
  <div class="button">Dummy link</div>
</div>



This approach satisfies the 1st and 2nd of the required behaviors listed above, but not the 3rd. Clicks on the dummy button are not passed to the a element below.
If I use pointer-events: none on the dummy button to pass the click through to the a element, then there is no hover animation on the dummy button, which violates the 1st requirement. Applying that same property with the :hover or :active pseudo-selectors gets me close, but then the 3rd requirement is violated once again.
I tried placing the a element on top (i.e., removing z-index: 1 ; from the dummy button) to meet the 3rd requirement; then, no clicks would need to pass through the dummy button to reach the link. However, the dummy button was then underneath the a element, so it no longer received hovers, which violated the 1st requirement.
I attempted to address this by using sibling selectors to turn on the dummy button's hover effect when the a element is hovered. However, the dummy button then appeared "hovered" when the cursor was anywhere in the container, not only when the cursor was directly over the button, violating the 2nd requirement.
This has got me stumped. I would appreciate any recommendations on how to achieve this affect with the above requirements (once again, looking for HTML/CSS solutions ONLY).
EDIT: Right under "What I've tried," I mentioned that I wanted to avoid wrapping the entire thing in an a tag, but I neglected to mention why. It is because I will have additional, unrelated links inside the container, and since I can't nest a tags, the container cannot be an a element. I just want to avoid having multiple links that point to the same place. Apologies for the confusion.

Do you care which mouse cursor the user (link vs default) sees when hovering in the space between the button and the container?

@j08691 Thanks for the edit; I do not know how to create that box you added with the live code snippet, but that is very helpful. To answer your question, I don't know which space between the two elements you are referring to, but the hope is that the user's cursor is the pointer (for links) the entire time they are inside the container.

Creating the runnable example is super easy. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

IMHO the whole thing creates a bad enough UX to begin with already (the whole container acting as a link, but only part of it - the button - signaling that to the user on hover), but your additional requirement of putting more, unrelated links into the container as well, makes it even worse.

The requirement seems so weird that I'm just making sure I fully understand. You want the user to be able to click on certain parts of the card that contain links to go to different places, but if they click anywhere else on the card they go to one place. Is that correct?

"...unrelated links inside the container..." - @Fitzkrieg Really? The <a> covers the entire container edge to edge. What you really want is a parent element with an [href] that has children elements that have their own [href] with unique urls. That's bad UX and essentially invalid HTML for a good reason. If the user hovers over any <a> (or <area>) with a [href], the behavior while hovering (cursor: pointer) indicates that clicking it should take the user elsewhere. Obscuring that ability makes accidental clicks send the user somewhere they most likely never wanted to go to.

Make the container a link and swap out the inner link for a span since it's redundant anyway.


.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 16px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button {
  z-index: 1;
  width: min-content;
  height: min-content;
  padding: 8px;
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
}

.button:hover {
  background: darkred;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<a href="#" class="container">
  <span class="cover">Not a real link</span>
  <div class="button">Dummy link</div>
</a>




Thank you for the response. This pointed out to me that I forgot an important detail. I have since updated my question.

You can safely place <div> inside <a> - it will be valid. Next, you can disable the styles for <a> and provide a cursor: pointer to the <div> button:


.container {
  all: unset;
  position: relative;
  /* This is the important one, the rest is styling */
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 16px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  padding: 8px;
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  
}

.button:hover {
  background: darkred;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<a href="#" class="container">
  <div class="button">Dummy link</div>
</a>




Thank you for the response. This pointed out to me that I forgot an important detail. I have since updated my question.

First, this is really bad UX imo. Second, does it has to be an <a>? If it just need to take user to a linked page, a <form> would do the same.


.container {
  position: relative;
  /* This is the important one, the rest is styling */
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 16px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  z-index: 1;
  /* This is the important one, the rest is styling */
  width: min-content;
  height: min-content;
  padding: 8px;
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
}

.button:hover {
  background: darkred;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cover {
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
<!-- onsubmit is used for demo, just remove it in your real code -->
<form action="#" class="container" onsubmit="alert('clicked');return false;">
  <input type="submit" id="real-link" class="cover">
  <label class="button" for="real-link">Dummy link</label>
</form>




Try this :


.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 16px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  z-index: 1;
  width: min-content;
  height: min-content;
  padding: 8px;
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.container:hover > .button {
  background: darkred;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.cover {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
<div class="container">
    <a class="cover" href="#">Real link</a>
    <div class="button">Dummy link</div>
 </div>




Flag 'Try This: {code}' Answers as "Very Low Quality"
